# How to make multiple relation ManyToMany in same table

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have my User entity. I would like to ask if it is possible to define several ManyToMany relations. I would like to connect these users with each other. For example, a leader should have several partners, a partner of several sellers. Of course, I added ManyToMany three times, I created the right tables and I can also add to them without any problem. The problem arises when I want to get this data all the time, it returns PersistanceCollection after which I am not able to iterate - it simply does not get any values. He sees this persistance but unfortunately I can't do anything about it. I know that this is an unusual solution, but it will work very well in my system. Unless someone has a different idea on how to connect users to each other, as described above.

User Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="liders")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_lider")
 */
private $lider;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="lider")
 */
private $liders;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="partners")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_partner")
 */
private $partner;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="partner")
 */
private $partners;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="sellers")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_seller")
 */
private $seller;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="seller")
 */
private $sellers;



public function __construct()
{
    $this->systemNotifications = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->invoices = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->lider = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->liders = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->partner = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->partners = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->seller = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->sellers = new ArrayCollection();

}
```

PersistanceCollection:

```
User^ {#728 ▼
  -id: 10
  -email: ""
  -roles: array:1 [▶]
  -password: ""
  -details: array:17 [▶]
  -invoices: PersistentCollection^ {#733 ▶}
  -systemNotifications: PersistentCollection^ {#724 ▶}
  -registercode: ""
  -lider: PersistentCollection^ {#732 ▶}
  -liders: PersistentCollection^ {#731 ▶}
  -partner: PersistentCollection^ {#727 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: User^ {#728}
    -association: array:20 [ …20]
    -em: EntityManager^ {#268 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "partners"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#341 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection^ {#729 ▶}
    #initialized: false
  }
  -partners: PersistentCollection^ {#723 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: User^ {#728}
    -association: array:16 [ …16]
    -em: EntityManager^ {#268 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "partner"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#341 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection^ {#722 ▶}
    #initialized: false
  }
  -seller: PersistentCollection^ {#721 ▶}
  -sellers: PersistentCollection^ {#736 ▶}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " it simply does not get any values"? Because it's the way that Doctrine fetch relations (lazy)

Comment: have you try to iterate PersistentCollection object ?